# How do I configure the options in Highcharts to allow multiple drilldowns asynchronously?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to convert the following options in Highcharts to multiple series with multiple drilldowns. The problem is that I've changed the loop to progress over the points so as to add both drilldown series. However, in the loop I've written, it seems to be the case that after one go through the loop, the points array is overwritten with nulls, which makes the whole thing irrelevant.

I'm a beginner with the options, and after having spent quite a bit of time on it I can't crack it. An explanation and a solution would be an ideal answer to the question: "How do I do the following with multiple drilldowns?" It's all asynchronous requests on datasets.

I'm starting with

```
        options.chart = options.chart || {};
        options.chart.events = options.chart.events || {};
        var dd = options.chart.events.drilldown || function(e) {};
        options.chart.events.drilldown = function(e) {
            var chart = this;
            chart._drilldowns = chart._drilldowns || {};
            var series = chart._drilldowns[e.point.drilldown];
            if (series) {
                e.seriesOptions = series;
                chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
                dd(e);
            }
            if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                chart.showLoading('Fetching data...');
                $.getJSON(
                    '%(url)s?' + analytics.get_form_data(),
                    function(drilldowns) {
                        chart.hideLoading();
                        chart._drilldowns = drilldowns;
                        var series = drilldowns[e.point.drilldown];
                        chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
                        e.seriesOptions = series;
                        dd(e);
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    ''' % {'url': self.get_drilldown_url()}
```

and I've tried to change the second part to:

```
...
                    function(drilldowns) {
                        chart.hideLoading();
                        chart._drilldowns = drilldowns;
                        e.points.forEach(function(value, key){
                            var series = drilldowns[value.drilldown];
                            chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(value, series);
                        })
                        e.seriesOptions = series;
                        dd(e);
                    }
                );
            }
        };
```

But I don't get both my series drilling down. I actually get a `Property xAxis of null is not allowed` error, as when I go through the loop the second time, the set of points has been changed to null.

**UPDATE**

We eventually fixed (actually a collegue did!) using promises. We engineered it to wait until the first async request for data was retrieved, and then called `addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown` on each one until we hit the last one (derived off the chart state) at which point we called `addSeriesAsDrilldown` which does the `applyDrilldown` as part of the code.

Answer (score 6):

It's not the part of official API, but this way you can get multiple drilldowns: http://jsfiddle.net/p2xw9416/

In the lowest level of AJAX requests (if you have multiple of them), add each series as single object:

```
chart.hideLoading();
chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series_1);
chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series_2);
chart.applyDrilldown(); // update && animate
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is how to deal with the some events (corresponding to the number of series) that are fired. I get one event for each of the points from the doDrilldown function. I then need to know when to call `applyDrilldown()`, but I don't know how many events I'm going to receive.

Comment: Why do you have multiple calls for `drilldown` event? There should be one, see: http://jsfiddle.net/p2xw9416/1/ ("test" in console is visible only once per each drilldown).

Comment: if you look at the code in drilldown.src.js, you'll see that when drilling down multiple series asynchonously, the code fires an event for each point to be drilled down. Also, the example you posted duplicates the drilled down series. Not sure how it's doing that.

Comment: Please, create jsFiddle demo, even with static data just for an example. See mine example with two separate datasets: http://jsfiddle.net/p2xw9416/2/